# Output from API automatically stops

Tags: java, http, netbeans

I am making an application in java in which I am required to get latitude and longitude of certain locations listed in the csv file. All is going smooth but the response stops coming after sometime. Sometimes it parses the complete set of locations and sometimes it stops in between. I am not able to catch the flaw, please help me. The code is written below

```
 `int count=0;
 JFileChooser  jfc;
String path_of_chosen_file;
File directory_of_chosen_file;
ArrayList<String> locations;
FileWriter writer = null;

 private void browseBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          


    jfc = new JFileChooser();
    if(jfc.showOpenDialog(this) == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        //code to handle choosed file here.
        jfilenametxt.setText(jfc.getName(jfc.getSelectedFile()));
        path_of_chosen_file = jfc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        directory_of_chosen_file=jfc.getCurrentDirectory();
        System.out.println(path_of_chosen_file);
    }
}    
   private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // TODO add your handling code here:

    FileInputStream fileIn = null;
    locations=new ArrayList();

    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {

        scanner = new Scanner(new File(path_of_chosen_file));
        scanner.useDelimiter(",");
        while(scanner.hasNextLine())
        {
            locations.add(scanner.nextLine());             
        }
        locations.removeAll(Arrays.asList("", null));  
 }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e1){
    }

      String writepath=directory_of_chosen_file.toString() 
    +"/newfile"+jfc.getName(jfc.getSelectedFile());


   FileWriter writer = null;

 try {

 writer = new FileWriter(writepath);
     try{
         Iterator itr=locations.iterator(); 
         while(itr.hasNext())
         {

             String pointLocation=(String) itr.next();
             System.out.println(pointLocation);
        String latLongs[] = getLatLongPositions( pointLocation);



        writer.append(pointLocation);
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append(latLongs[0]);
        writer.append(',');
        writer.append(latLongs[1]);
           writer.append('\n');
            writer.flush();


        System.out.println("Your excel file has been generated for " + pointLocation);
         }
         Object[] options = { "OK" };
 int input = JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null, "Excel generation is 
  completed. Click OK to continue", "",
   JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE,
   null, options, options[0]);
          if(input == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
            {
                 System.out.println("AASHIMA");
            }
     }

     catch(Exception e1){
                  }

    } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
     try {
     writer.flush();
     writer.close();
     } catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
 }
    }
   } 

 `

public static String[] getLatLongPositions(String address) throws Exception
   {
  int responseCode = 0;
  String api = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + 
  URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8") + "&sensor=true";
System.out.println("URL : "+api);
URL url = new URL(api);
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

httpConnection.connect();

responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

if(responseCode == 200)
{
  DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
  Document document = builder.parse(httpConnection.getInputStream());
  XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
  XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
  XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/GeocodeResponse/status");
  String status = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
  if(status.equals("OK"))
  {
     expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lat");
     String latitude = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
     expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lng");
     String longitude = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);


     return new String[] {latitude, longitude};
  }
  else
  {
     throw new Exception("Error from the API - response status: "+status);
  }
}

return null;
}
```

The output on console is this
`Guwahati Assam india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Guwahati+Assam+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Guwahati Assam india
Muzaffarpur Bihar india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Muzaffarpur+Bihar+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Muzaffarpur Bihar india
Forbesganj Bihar india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Forbesganj+Bihar+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Forbesganj Bihar india
Ambikapur Chhattisgharh india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Ambikapur+Chhattisgharh+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Ambikapur Chhattisgharh india
Raipur Chhattisgharh india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Raipur+Chhattisgharh+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Raipur Chhattisgharh india
Surat Gujarat india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Surat+Gujarat+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Surat Gujarat india
Vadodara Gujarat india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Vadodara+Gujarat+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Vadodara Gujarat india
Rajkot Gujarat india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Rajkot+Gujarat+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Rajkot Gujarat india
Panchkula Haryana india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Panchkula+Haryana+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Panchkula Haryana india
Deogharh Jharkhand india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Deogharh+Jharkhand+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Deogharh Jharkhand india
Jamshedpur Jharkhand india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Jamshedpur+Jharkhand+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Jamshedpur Jharkhand india
Hosur karnataka india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Hosur+karnataka+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Hosur karnataka india
Belgaum karnataka india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Belgaum+karnataka+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Belgaum karnataka india
Gwalior Madhya Pradesh india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Gwalior+Madhya+Pradesh+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Gwalior Madhya Pradesh india
Narsimhapur Madhya Pradesh india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Narsimhapur+Madhya+Pradesh+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Narsimhapur Madhya Pradesh india
Pune Maharashtra india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Pune+Maharashtra+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Pune Maharashtra india
Nanded Maharashtra india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Nanded+Maharashtra+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Nanded Maharashtra india
Nagpur Maharashtra india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Nagpur+Maharashtra+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Nagpur Maharashtra india
Kolhapur Maharashtra india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Kolhapur+Maharashtra+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Kolhapur Maharashtra india
Sangali Maharashtra india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Sangali+Maharashtra+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Sangali Maharashtra india
Navi Mumbai Maharashtra india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Navi+Mumbai+Maharashtra+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Navi Mumbai Maharashtra india
Ri Bhoi Meghalaya india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Ri+Bhoi+Meghalaya+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Ri Bhoi Meghalaya india
Sambalpur Orissa india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Sambalpur+Orissa+india&sensor=true
Your excel file has been generated for Sambalpur Orissa india
Chunni Punjab india
URL : http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=Chunni+Punjab+india&sensor=true

here it stops and is not progressing. Also the control is returned back to the UI where the button again attains the unpressed state.

it completely executes randomly. Here is the screenshot
[image]

The response code is 200 and still I am facing the same problem
[image]

I have found the problem, please suggest a solution so that I can get the desired result

[image]

Comment: WHere do the URLs in your console come from? They are not in the code you pasted here?

Comment: @StephaneM Please check it now

Comment: You're using the google API without API key. There are restrictions on the number of requests you can make for free. My guess is that sometimes you do not get the expected HTTP 200 return code, then getLatLongPositions returns `null`, then in jButton2ActionPerformed you get a ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException that is not caught so you pass silently in the finally block and exit.

Comment: @StephaneM but when I run the code again it sometimes give the expected output as depicted in the screen shot. Why is this happening if it is about restrictions ?

Comment: The limit is 50 requests per seconds, maybe sometimes your computer is busy and runs slower so it passes. Anyhow you should test for http response code different from 200 and trace something to the console to make sure this is really what happens.

Comment: ok I will check and get back to you

Comment: @StephaneM kindly check the screen shot I attached. This time it stopped on the very first iteration

Comment: @StephaneM Kindly see the screen shot I attached lastly. The problem is clearly visible i,e.. OVER_QUERY_LIMIT. Provide me a solution please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155301/discussion-between-aashima-anand-and-stephanem).

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. The issue was due to OVER_QUERY_LIMIT , so I checked the status of it and called the function recursively after some timeout. Here is the code.

```
    public static String[] getLatLongPositions(String address) throws Exception
 {
  int responseCode = 0;
  String api = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=" + 
 URLEncoder.encode(address, "UTF-8") + "&sensor=true";
System.out.println("URL : "+api);
URL url = new URL(api);
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

httpConnection.connect();

responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
System.out.println("The response code is: " +responseCode);

if(responseCode == 200)
{

  DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();

  Document document = builder.parse(httpConnection.getInputStream());

  XPathFactory xPathfactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
  XPath xpath = xPathfactory.newXPath();
  XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("/GeocodeResponse/status");

  String status = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);

  System.out.println("the status is " +status);
  if(status.equals("OK"))
  {

     expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lat");
     String latitude = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);
     expr = xpath.compile("//geometry/location/lng");
     String longitude = (String)expr.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.STRING);


     return new String[] {latitude, longitude};
  }
  if (status.equals("OVER_QUERY_LIMIT")) {    
       TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(20);
           return( getLatLongPositions(address));


    }
  else
  {
     throw new Exception("Error from the API - response status: "+status);
  }
}

return null;
}`
```